# Возврат формы со значениями django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Проблема в том, что все required поля формы forms.Form, а тут они все обязательные, сбрасываются при отправке формы, а нужно сбросить только неверные.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.POST.get('default', False):
        infosystems = list(self.get_infosystem())
        self.set_single_threats_factors(infosystems)
        self.set_group_factors(infosystems)
        for infosystem in infosystems:
            infosystem.save()
        self.typical_infosystem.refresh_from_db()
    else:
        pk = request.POST.get('infosystem', None)
        system = get_object_or_404(InfoSystem, pk=pk)
        form = InitialProtectionsForm(data=request.POST, infosystem=system)
        if form.is_valid():
            for group in CODES_HASH:
                factor_value = request.POST.get(group, None)
                if factor_value is not None:
                    set_group_factor_value(system, group, request.POST.get(group, None))
            system.save()
        # пытался так
        # else: 
        #     return self.get(request, InitialProtectionsForm(request.POST, infosystem=system))
            # form = InitialProtectionsForm(request.POST, infosystem=system)
            # system.save()

    company_changed_data.send(company=self.company, sender=self.__class__)
    return super(FeaturesView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: else:
        pk = request.POST.get('infosystem', None)
если что с этого начинается обработка моего запроса